# Writing a Sonar rule checking loops

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've noticed when a behavior is checked "inside loops", Sonar rule check for "for" loops, "foreach" loops and "while" loops : "`Kind.FOR_STATEMENT`, `Kind.FOR_EACH_STATEMENT` and `Kind.WHILE_STATEMENT`" (see rule 'java:S3012' for example)

I can see why `Kind.DO_STATEMENT` (do... while) is not listed because it's rarely used (even if it could be added at no cost) but why `stream().forEach(...)` is not taken into account ?

Is it something possible with Sonar and static analysis ? Or is it considered out of static analysis scope ?

Comment: It's certainly possible. It's probably just difficult. With a regular for-loop, the AST can be traversed pretty simply. With a lambda expression, it's somewhat akin to writing `for (Foo foo : theFoos) { doSomething(); }` The thing that's actually invoked is a separate function. It has a separate stack frame. I would bet that Sonar doesn't do a great job of inferring context across method invocations for regular for-loops either. It might be able to manage it for private methods, but I doubt it does more than that.

Comment: You're right, I guess Sonar doesn't follow method calls for this kind of check. But it would be nice to have a definition/perimeter of what static analysis should cover.